# Can you mock a value rather than a method?

Tags: scala

Hi there I have a private method that has a few different bits going on inside. This method is passed a Future[A], is there anyway to mock this future value, as I don't what to mock the whole method as I am mocking the method calls going on inside this method. Thanks, Jackie

```
private def showSomething(id: String, accountData: Future[AccountData]): = {
  accountData zip someService.getSomething(id) map {
    case (accountData, somethingElse) => // do something
  }
}
```

So I would like to mock the accountData Future passed into the showSomething method, is there any way to do this? Thanks

Comment: It would depend on where that value comes from in your code, and how that method is invoked

Comment: Please show how are you calling `showSomething`.

Answer (score 2):

If you know what value you need in `accountData` Future, why not just pass `Future.successful(yourMockedValue)`?